# Jenkins Github Organization exclude commits from certain users

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Using a Github Organizations folder, is there a way to prevent a pipeline from running if a commit is submitted by a specific user?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step of your pipeline, you could use `git` to get the name of the author of HEAD.

Fail or skip the rest of the pipeline, if it is your special user.